# Replace broken images with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, replace

I have a web page that includes 10's of thousands of images. Sometimes the image isn't available so a broken image is displayed in the clients browser.

The broken image is in the following URL format: **www.domain.com/t.php?src=p/dd5e5b08_1.jpg**.

How do I use jQuery to get the set of images, filter it to broken images then replace the `src`?

The following does not work:

*above the closing `</head>` tag*

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

*above the closing  tag*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("img").each(function(){
            var image = $(this);
            if(image.context.naturalWidth == 0 || image.readyState == 'uninitialized'){
                $(image).unbind("error").attr("src", "/images/no_image.png");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code might help you:

```
function imgError(image){
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
    return true;
}

<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

Try [CodeFiddle Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/udlbuR)

Comment: how do you set dynamically <img src="image.png" ?

Comment: get image on php variable and use it like this:
<img src="<?php echo $image ?>">

Comment: What is `return true` for?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let images = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg'];
    let image_html = '';
    $.each(images, (key, value) => {
        image_html += '<img src="img/' + value + '"/>';
    });
    $('#imgcontainer').html(image_html);
    $('img').on('error', function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<img src="img/no-photo.jpg"/>');
    });
});
```